# Localhost:8080 is refusing to connect on my galaxy a32

Tags: android, visual-studio, localhost

When trying to get visual studios on my android I got localhost, at first it worked fine but the next day it refused to connect. I tried everything I could, like changing the proxy settings to none (it was already on none so that didn’t work) and saw recommendations to turn off firewall temporarily but I couldn’t, how would I be able to fix it without something like a root.

Comment: Can you re-explain what you are trying to do? This statement "When trying to get visual studios on my android I got localhost,.." doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Sorry, watched this tutorial https://youtu.be/59kKxZV5_Nk to get visual studios in android. Hope that’s enough information.

Comment: Do you trying on your own phone or on an emulator?

Comment: Own phone, I have a feeling that I won’t be able to fix this problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.